# How to sign messages on the server side using web3

Tags: node.js, cryptography, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I am building a decentralized app using Node.js. I need the node.js app to receive a message from the frontend, use web3.js to sign the message and send the signature back to the frontend.

I am thinking of passing as a environmental variable a predefined private key to the node.js app. Then use the private key to instantiate `Web3` and call `web3.personal.sign` to sign the message. I need the signing process to occur on the server side, so I don't believe that using a client-side wallet like Metamask would be applicable.

I am new to Blockchain and Web3 development so I am not sure if what I am asking is feasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the private key to [wallet.add()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add), and then sign the message using [web3.eth.sign()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/web3-eth.html#sign).

```
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY);
const message = "Hello world";

// sign
const signature = await web3.eth.sign(message, SIGNER_ADDRESS);

// recover
const recoveredSigner = web3.eth.accounts.recover(message, signature);
console.log(recoveredSigner == SIGNER_ADDRESS);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do I have to add the private key to the wallet? What if I pass the private key into the `sign()` method? Also, I can recover the signer address from a signature in a smart contract using solidity, right?

Comment: Also, is this a valid way to instantiate `web3`? 

var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

Comment: The signing process is currently (v1.7 of web3js) only available through the list of wallet if you want to sign the message on the backend, not possible to pass the private key just to the `sign()` function. However you can [remove()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-remove) the wallet afterwards.

Comment: Solidity can recover the signer address using native function `ecrecover()` or you can use an opensource implementation that wraps this function, for example OpenZeppelin's [EDCSA](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol).

Comment: That's a valid way of instantiating the instance. If you want to connect to a node of the network (such as Ethereum), you can pass its URL in the optional constructor param. Example: `var web3 = new Web3("https://127.0.0.1:8545");`

Comment: I am using ethers js. Which one is good ethers js or web3 js